# When parsing a Word document using powershell, how to determine if the selected text is inside a table?

Tags: microsoft-word, powershell

I've written a powershell script to open an existing Word document and parse its contents. If the selected text is inside a table, I need to parse it in a different manner. I've not been able to discover how to indicate the selection is inside a table cell. I've been searching the internet for days looking for a solution and found none. Any help is greately appreciated. Partial snippet follows:

```
$doc = $word.Documents.Open($Filename)
#Hide Word to avoid unnecessary distraction on the monitor
$word.Visible = $false
$sel = $word.Selection 
$paras = $doc.Paragraphs 

foreach ($para in $paras) 
{
    $ParaText = $para.Range.Text

}
```

Comment: how did you parse the document? By extracting the docx file and parsing the xml files or by some other components? Please show your code

Comment: please [edit] your question an include all the necessary info, not in a comment